Mathematica/Wolfram engine on general ARM64 Linux platform
As we know there is one (and probably the only one) ARM distro of Mathematica, that is the one for raspberry pi. So my question is if there is a method to install this version of Mathematica or at least let it run in a container on a general ARM64 Linux device? What should I do? Can any one give an outlined procedure?
Here are what I have tried:
A. Directly run the installation script on Ubuntu22.04 arm, the error occurs after the downloading of wolfram engine and wolfram script is done:
Redading packages list…Error
E:read still have 8 to read but none left
E:…(I forgot)
Is this because of lacking packages or architectures? I’m new to Linux…
B.using docker to use wolfram  engine. At the final step activating wolfram engine I get to know the image is an amd64 one, it can not be used in a arm64 platform. So this way definitely fails.
As I have seen a post on the forum that installs raspberry's pi version wolfram engine on an android device, similar procedure should be easier to be done on a genuine Linux device? Again I am to unfamiliar with Linux…. Thanks guys!
———///tried dpkg .deb from RPi community///——-following @ihojinicki ‘s advice
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wolfram-engine:
 wolfram-engine depends on libgfortran5; however:
  Package libgfortran5 is not installed.
 wolfram-engine depends on libxcb-cursor0; however:
  Package libxcb-cursor0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wolfram-engine (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wolfram-engine
```


I have it installed on a Debian Bookworm aarch64 VM.  Just grab the deb and install it via apt/dpkg.

Following ihojnicki’s comment I have successfully installed and activated Wolfram engine and Mathematica(RPi
ARM64) version on a Debian 12 VM working on UTM@M1iPadPro IPad OS 16.2. I’m running the benchmark of Mathematica and will post the result later.
The outlined procedure on an over-complete Debian12 VM is very simple.(The word over-complete because to avoid package/archintecthre/…. missing errors I installed every possible packages when net-install Debian12 on the VM).
First download the latest arm64 version Mathematica .deb on enter link description here and then spit the deb by:
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb

Then go through the configuration page and you can directly activate Mathematica on its GUI.
Now the problem left is why doing the similar procedure outputs errors on ARM64 Ubuntu, I guess it’s because the lack of some environment that is not contained in the slimmest system image(?) A equivalent question is which packages are needed for install and run Mathematica RPi on ARM64 Linux
